# Why do scrollbars stop working when the mouse is too far away?

Tags: windows, user-interface

Dragging a (Windows) scrollbar only works as long as the cursor is not too far away from the scrollbar itself. How can I 'fix' this bevaviour? Is there some kind of threshold in the registry?

Tip: to see this behavior: click on a scrollbar (dont' release the mouse button) and move up/down. This works, as long as you don't move too much to the left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

No, seriously. Sometimes I'm somewhere in the middle of a long document and I want to briefly look at something far away without losing my place. I grab the scrollbar with the mouse, move to the part I want to look at, then move the mouse to the side before letting go of the button. This gets me back to where I was originally so I can continue reading.

Comment: This is exactly why I love that feature. +1 for that.

Comment: Ok, it's a feature. But is there a setting somewhere to disable it?

Comment: @compie: no sorry not that I know of.